# Exactly when are bindings updated?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

When a `DependencyProperty` is set, does the bound target (viewmodel) property get its new value immediately or does this happen asynchronously? E.g.:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Then I explicitly set the `IsEnabled` property:

```
textBox.IsEnabled = false;
```

I know about the [UpdateSourceTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) setting, and I believe this question is mostly relevant for the default `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is immediately and synchronously.

**The long story**

I would not mix `UpdateSourceTrigger` with (a)synchronicity of the binding. The first defines how often the source property should be updated e.g. when a control loses focus or maybe when the `UpdateSource` method is called...

On the another hand the synchronicity of a given binding defines if get/set operations of a source property are performed synchronously or asynchronously. In practice you will only see a difference if reading a source property might take a long time. In that case by default UI will be blocked.

You can control the synchronicity of the binding via [Binding.IsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Here is an example showing a difference. Let's start with XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Button Click="Button_Click">Update</Button>
```

And here is a code behind. `MainWindow` has `Text` property which is a source of a binding. If a button is clicked it is updated. If you examine `Text` property you will see that it takes 10 seconds to get its value.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            return _text;
        }

        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

If you run this code you will observe 2 things:

- The application starts slowly.
- If you click a button, the application hangs.

Now modify binding in this way:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text,Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=true}"/>
```

Run the application once again:

- The application starts immediately.
- If you click a button, the application doesn't hangs.

The similar excerise can be performed with a settter of `Text` property i.e. just move `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);` to the setter.

Answer (score 1):

you can give getter setter properties to textbox field and find how this working
like ..string st  get { return _type; }
    set { _type = value; }..and so you will get chance to chnage values or you can apply validation